# add item to my stringarray

Tags: android

I have my category_array(String array) in my String.xml file.
I use this string-array to populate a listview.

```
<string-array name="category_array">
    <item >Airplane</item>
    <item >Train</item>
    <item >Taxi</item>
    <item >Bus</item>
    <item >Food</item>
    <item >Drink</item>
    <item >Meeting Entrata</item>
</string-array>
```

Can I add an item getted from an editText from my Activity, to my category_array??

Answer (score 2):

Its not possible, strings.xml file is read-only. you can't edit this file at run-time.

Answer (score 0):

No, you **cannot** add items to a string-array dynamically. What you define in resources is always what you will get.

Resources are defined as `public static final` in `R`.

Answer (score 0):

No, resources aren't editable. Use database instead.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing can be added in String.xml during runtime.
For every item in string.xml.Android SDK provides a static integer during compile.i.e., in R.java file.
So you can edit it during runtime if you need to any item during runtime i prefer you to use either ArrayList or Map

Answer (score 0):

You can not add data xml dynamically its used for static data which are not going to change in entire project.

```
Vector<String> vecString=new Vector<String>();
```

Then you can add strings dynamically...

```
vecString.add("Your Item1");
vecString.add("Your Item1");
```